# How can I render a Django render() response in an ajax function?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

In my view, I return html if a form is valid:

```
if form_valid():
    return render(request, 'home.html', context=context)
else:
    return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

I'm submitting multiple forms via ajax and want to render the response, if the status code is not 204:

```js
$.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    success: function (response, status, jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.status !== 204) {
            document.write(response); // this works, but I lose some functionality. Some buttons stop working.
            // How can I render the response correctly?
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: The buttons that don't work anymore. It's a form using bootstrap collapse with some workarounds

main.html

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}


    {% include 'collapse_form.html' with form=mysql_form %}
    {% include 'collapse_form.html' with form=postgres_form %}
    {% include 'collapse_form.html' with form=sqlite_form %}

    <input type="hidden" name="databases-section"/>

    <a id="download-btn" class="btn btn-success">Download</a>
    <a id="hidden-download-link" class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#download"></a>
</form>
```

collapse_form.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}

<div class="collapseForm">
    <div class="collapseFormButton">
        <button id="collapseBtn" class="d-none btn btn-check p-0 m-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#{{ form.prefix }}-collapseTarget"
                aria-expanded="false">
        </button>

        {{ form.active|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="{{ form.prefix }}-collapseTarget">
        <div class="card card-body">
            {{ form|as_crispy_errors }}
            {% for field in form.visible_fields|slice:"1:" %}
                {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.collapseFormButton').find("input").change(function () {
        toggleCollapseForm()
    });

function toggleCollapseForm() {
    let collapseForm = $(".collapseForm");

    collapseForm.each(function () {
        let collapseCheckbox = $(this).find("input[id*='active']");
        let collapseTarget = $(this).find("div[id*='collapseTarget']");

        if (collapseCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
            collapseTarget.collapse('show');
        } else {
            collapseTarget.collapse('hide');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on the "some buttons stop working" part? That seems to be the issue, and I'm not sure how to help if I don't know what part isn't working.

Comment: I updated the question with some details, thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

instead of `document.write` there is more functions like `append`, you could use that to append the `rendered htmls` cooming to ajax as a response to a specific element selected by `id` to avoid any problem like lossing the documents html tags(`html, body, header`) .
and there is big point!

### javascript has different behavior regarding dynamically added elements!

to be more clear, I think js and/or jQuery has different behavior for keword `this` which doesn't work on dynamically added elements. so you sould use another query-selector like `$(document).on('click', element, function (){....}` and this would work as expected.